# Retry logic of Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Let me get straight to the question. I have two questions relating to the Quartz Scheduler working with a JDBC job store.

1. Suppose if my app crashes, I know that quartz will retry the jobs that should have been fired during the down time. What about the jobs that were getting executed at that point of time? And what about the failed retries which were happening? Would they also be handled?
2. What is this option? - `org.quartz.jobStore.maxMisfiresToHandleAtATime` in the properties file? Is it the maximum number of misfires that quartz will handle once it comes back up after say a crash?

Thanks in advance